# Monitoring Tomcat response time

Tags: tomcat, monitoring

I have a standard use case of monitoring the response time of the requests hitting my Tomcat server. I have enabled the access log and added to the pattern the response time (%D).

Now I would like to monitor the response time of my server. For example:

1. What was the avarege response time in the last hour?
2. What was the the median response time in the last hour?
3. What was the 90% response time in the last hour?

etc.

Do I have a tool that can provide me these statistics with charts?

Yosi

Answer (score 3):

I think [JavaMelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) can do what you want. It's very easy to set up and gives you some pretty nice graphs of more or less useful information. (The response time you mentioned is included)

Answer (score 0):

There are many monitoring systems out there, that can help you. Nagios is for sure one of the most well known. Others include [RHQ](http://rhq-project.org/), also allow you to monitor e.g. VM and OS statistics in addition to the response time stats.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Splunk?   It's ability to process logs and visualize the data is quite well known.